# If a monotonous bounded function can reach value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$

Tags: calculus

If a monotonous bounded function can reach every value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then Prove it is continuous on $[a,b]$.

It is easy to see the conclusion when you sketch a graph. Since it can reach every value, then it can not have discontinuity point. But how to express this strictly.

Comment: I'm guessing these are real functions? Monotonicity is a term that is used more generally than in real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is monotonically increasing and not continuous at a point $c$. Let $\alpha $ and $\beta$ be the left hand and right limits of the function at $c$. These limits exist by monotonicity; in fact $\alpha =\sup \{f(t):t<c\}$ and $\beta =\inf \{f(t):t>c\}$. Also $\alpha < \beta $. If $\alpha <y <\beta$ then $f$ does not attain the value $y$ since $f \leq \alpha <y$ on $[a,c]$ and $f \geq \beta >y$ on $[c,b]$. This contradiction proves that $f$ is continuous. A similar argument works for edcreasing fun ctions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be non-decreasing, fix $c\in(a,b)$ and some $\epsilon>0$.We note that $f(a)\le f(c)$.

If $f(c)-\epsilon/2<f(a)$,put $x_1=a$. If $f(a)\le f(c)-\epsilon/2\le f(c)$, then by IVP we have a $x_0<c$ such that $f(x_1)=f(c)-\epsilon/2$

In either case we get for $x\in(x_1,c]\Rightarrow f(c)-\epsilon/2=f(x_0)\le f(x)\le f(c)$.

Similarly we can get an $x_2>c$ such that $x\in[c,x_2)\Rightarrow f(c)\le f(x)\le f(x_2)=f(c)+\epsilon/2$.

Take $\delta=min\{c-x_1,x_2-c\}$, then clearly $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ implies $$f(c)-\epsilon/2\le f(x)\le f(c)+\epsilon/2\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$.

[Similar argument works at $c=a,b$].

Comment: IVP? do you mean intermediate value theorem?

Comment: I meant intermediate value property, we are given the function follows this property.

Comment: But it is a property of continuous function, and notice that this is what we want to proof.

Comment: You stated that f can reach any value in between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ right, that's what I call IVP